# What's the difference between real dual-touch and fake dual-touch?

Tags: sony-xperia-x10-mini-pro, multi-touch

I have a `Xperia X10 Mini Pro` and by some ungodly reason it's dual touch feature is not working. I have searched around the net and I have seen here and there people use terms such as `real dual-touch` and `fake dual-touch`.
I don't really understand what's the difference here? Can the dual-touch ability be faked and how is that possible?
By the way, if anyone can tell is it possible to activate the dual touch feature in my phone I would be super thankful.

Comment: I have 2 questions. Is your phone rooted and what ROM are you using (EX custom ROM, Gingerbread Stock, etc)?

Comment: It's rooted. I use GingerDX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multitouch touch screen digitizers handle (2,3,4...) or more input fingers at a time at the hardware level.
Single touch devices handle only one finger at a time even if 2 or more are present. If you touch with a 2nd finger, the detected touch will "**jump**" from the first finger to the second finger location.

Install a touch screen visualizer or test application like [Z device test](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=zausan.zdevicetest).
You can watch a video how it looks with one finger on [youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yXKheRdyTzs) (which has fake dual touch and has some flaws).

So what a fake dual touch driver does is this:
It basically detects "**jumps**" of the finger and assumes it comes from a second and just keeps reporting a fixed virtual event (coming from the last known position from the (now vanished) 1st finger touch) while the 2nd touch is from your actual finger and reported regularly.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between real dual-touch and fake dual-touch has to do with how the screen is built. Real touch screens have an additional layer to allow for additional inputs. There are ways to emulate dual-touch with software. This is helpful in the case of your particular phone.

This [XDA forum page](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1009008&highlight=mod%20dualtouch) has a list of updates for particular ROMs including 2 stock ROMs which enable fake dual touch.